# Android Bluetooth Low Energy Motorola API pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on using the BT 4.0 API that Motorola has provided with the RAZR.  In [one of their documents](http://developer.motorola.com/docs/bluetooth-low-energy-api/) it states to use the Android API to pair before connecting and using their framework.  Per their instructions I have been pairing with OS Bluetooth settings application, but it never prompts me for a key.  It will pair but doesn't appear to bond, and this is critical for me.

My question is, when they say "using the Android API" is this referring to simply using the OS Bluetooth utility to pair before hand (like I have been doing), or is there some way to do it with code in my application.  They reference the "createBond()" function which, to my knowledge, is not an accessible function (at least not without some squirrely libraries or reflection).

Any advice is greatly appreciated, especially anyone who has used the API successfully, if they could give an account of their process.  I'm just looking for some clarity at this point :)

Answer (score 5):

Lloyd,

You are correct, follow the instructions in the link you posted.

Outside of coding, when they say use the standard android api for "non-le" operations, they mean go ahead and pair the ble device the same way you would any bluetooth classic devices inside android settings -> wireless & network -> bluetooth -> scan for devices.

If the device you are using is a motorola le compatible device the ble device will be **paired but not connected.**

Now, in the code, you can detect this paired device through the same method of

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices()
```

To double check if your Android Phone is LE compatible, run this code:

```
 public static boolean checkBLESupport() {
        boolean deviceSupportsLE;

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "rawtypes" })
        Class object = Class.forName("android.server.BluetoothGattService");
        deviceSupportsLE = true; 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        deviceSupportsLE = false; 
    }

    return deviceSupportsLE;
}
```

And to double check if the bluetooth device you paired is LE, when you are looping through the bonded devices.
Check the device with this code.

```
 if (device.getBluetoothClass() == null) {
    Log.i(TAG, "This device is BLE compatible");
        b = true;
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "This device is not BLE");
        b = false;
}
```

Now for establishing connection from your LE compatible phone to your LE compatible bluetooth device, follow the Gatt service instructions under the link you posted. http://developer.motorola.com/docs/bluetooth-low-energy-api/

Take note that under this example it is connecting to a bluetooth low energy heart rate monitor.

If you are not trying to connect to the heart rate monitor with LE heart rate profile, here is a link to another Motorola document that details creating your own LE Profile to use with the GATT framework. http://developer.motorola.com/docs/bluetooth-low-energy-gatt-framework-api/

**If the instructions are not clear enough at any point in either of these documents, motorola offers sample android applications using the frameworks in those documents.**

Comment: You can not pair with BLE inside android settings

Comment: With a BLE compatible phone. You can pair with BLE, I have a Droid RAZR and ble pairs just fine inside the standard android settings. I assume the Droid 4 will work as well. I have not tested other new devices such as Galaxy SIII, or HTC Evo 4gLTE

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about Bluetooth Low Energy? Because you are not pairing anything with a heart rate monitor talking BLE

Comment: Droid RAZR has been verified to work with a heart rate monitor talking BLE. The recent ICS update for the Droid RAZR broke BLE capability with the RAZR, but Motorola has stated they will release an update to fix that soon. As it stands, I have verified the RAZR does have BLE capability and it did connect with a few different BLE heart rate monitors (Polar H7, Wahoo Blue) on android 2.3.6.

Comment: That is interesting. What kind of pairing does it do, since there are no security or key-matching on those devices?

Comment: No pairing codes are required, it pairs up right away using the standard android bluetooth apis. I assume these apis make use of the bluetooth 2.1 SSP pairing method. Interestingly enough, after running scan for devices, if you select the heart rate monitor it pairs right up with a "Paired but not connected" message, but i have tested on other phones besides the RAZR, and scan for devices will not even return that it found the HRM. This makes me think that there is something additional with the hardware in the RAZR that allows the standard bluetooth pairing.

Comment: Any way for an application to programmatically do all the pairing/connecting necessary for communication with a totally new remote device (i.e. never seen before?). Requiring the user to manually connect through settings really cuts down on BLE use cases...

Answer (score 1):

I guess motorola stack has BLE support. But what i feel is that it does not pair with the devices that require bonding though It does work some sensors. I have tried with a proximity sensor that require bonding. It never gets paired though the devices is discovered with Razr which even does not with S3.

There's a helpful video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5Jo2YjjCuk).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but can confirm -

If your BLE Peripheral requires bonding, Moto X - and some other older Motorola devices - MUST be paired via Bluetooth Settings prior to programmatic connection via the Android GATT interface.

If you bond via the createBond method, or reading of an encrypted characteristic, your connection will be dropped typically in under 60 seconds, despite DDMS logs that show a good bond may be established.